# Is the exception message raised by a C# COMponent passed through interop to C++?

Tags: c#, c++, com, com-interop

If I implement a COM interface in a C# class, which will be called from a C++ module, then in case of a failure the C# code should throw an exception; this will be marshalled to a HRESULT failure code by the interop layer.

But will any message text (or other information) passed to the Exception constructor also be available to the calling C++ code? If so, how can it be obtained i.e. which API methods?

e.g. if in my C# code I do `throw new ArgumentException("The email address is invalid")` I would except my COM HRESULT to be `E_INVALIDARG` but will my custom text be marshalled or can I only look up a text description of `E_INVALIDARG`?

Comment: We already [went through this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33037504/17034).

Comment: You mentioned it in passing in a different question but my search on this interface did not clarify where it is implemented or how I obtain an interface pointer. If your answer is "yes, and you can get it through IErrorInfo" could you flesh that out a little? MSDN is not showing me anything concrete/specific so far.

Comment: @HansPassant it's also not clear in your referenced answer if the message will be a generic mapping to the COM HRESULT, or if the text I pass to a C# exception ctor will be marshalled. e.g `throw new ArgumentException("The email address is invalid")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's little known that the [`IErrorInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221233(v=vs.85).aspx) object (returned by [`GetErrorInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221032(v=vs.85).aspx)) also implements the [`_Exception`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.InteropServices._Exception(v=vs.90).aspx) COM interface, which exposes the public members of the [`System.Exception`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx) class to unmanaged code, including [`StackTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices._exception.stacktrace(v=vs.90).aspx), etc.

To access `_Exception` from C++, you'd need to import a correct version of `mscorlib.tlb`, e.g.:

```
#import "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
```

Comment: I shall investigate this and report back, sounds very interesting. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, you wouldn't be able to provide a code example how to use this would you? The documentation says "This interface is for access to managed classes from unmanaged code" but then only discusses managed code - assemblies, etc. Is this reliant on CLR? If not, what headers are needed?

Comment: Cool, thanks. I assume this is accessed through `QueryInterface` as normal? I'm not sure who voted you down or why for this.

Comment: @Mr.Boy, you can indeed just use `QueryInterface`, or use ATL and `ComQIPtr<_Exception>`, or remove `raw_interfaces_only` from the `#import` and VC++ should generate COM smart pointers for you. I care less about down-votes without relevant comments :)

Answer (score -1):

This is generally possible when implementing the interface [ISupportErrorInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221083(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Using it, not implementing it.  The CLR already implements ISupportErrorInfo and IErrorInfo.

Comment: also not `ISupportErrorInfo` but `IErrorInfo`.